# HTML table generated from MySQL results, to process in a form with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a simple MySQL database with some products (id, name, amount). The end result will be a PDF that has a page for every product (amount in database = default amount of how many pages of that product will be printed). Example: The database contains "1, Apples, 4". The end result will be a PDF that contains 4 pages with the word "Apples" on it. When I have 20 products in my database, the final PDF will contain all products with their respective 'page-amounts`.

I put all the products in a simple HTML table (in a form) with PHP. The end-user must be able to change the amount of pages for a product for just one time. So if there is "1, Apples, 4" in the database, the user should be able to make it "1, Apples, 8" for just one time. My guess is to put the 'default' amount in an input value-tag, but I don't see how to process the form...

I hope my story makes some sense. Current code:

```
<?php
# Database connection
include('includes/database.php');

# Query
$query = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 25" or die(mysqli_error());
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_left);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!--Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div id="main">

        <div id="content">

            <div class="table">

            <form action="" method="post">

            <table class="products">


<?php
# Begin while-loop
while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="products">
            <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="<?php echo $product['amount']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php
# End while-loop
} 
?>

            </table>

            </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whether you want to restrict user to update single time before submit or after submit?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I think he want to fetch data from table, fetched data can be edited and finally he wants to generate pdf out of it.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Define a column with numeric input in database table as page count and add a form on the page to get the values of the pages numbers from the user :

Here is the html code to add a form to get the number of pages :

```
<html> 
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
Number of Pages : <input type="number" name="pagenumber" min="1" max="8"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
<html>
```

This will add the input number into the table with numeric value, now all you have to do is just call this number from the database when generating output file and you can also use the loop like if the user has entered 4 number in the input the loop will start from this number and will decrement to 0. This how you will be able to get your required feature.

Comment: Maybe I wasn´t really clear in my question, but the final PDF will be all of the products together. So if there are 40 products with each a different ´amount´, you will get a PDF that has all of those pages at once, i.e. 80 pages.

Comment: you can use both as input with the same manner .. like you can ask the required amount and required product from the customer in same manner

Comment: I don't think I understand you. Because the table is dynamic, I can't  define default variables to get the values. That is where I'm struggling. The table works, the products are displayed perfectly, and the amount of pages is a nice input field with a default value from the database. But as I click on 'submit', all those products have to be 'pushed' to a PDF handler. Since the products change from time to time, I don't want to change my code everytime a product's added or edited. You get me?...